# Py2exe Error: No Commands Supplied

Tags: python, py2exe, setup.py

I'm trying to convert my Python programs with the Py2exe library with the following setup.py code below:

```
    from distutils.core import setup
    import py2exe

    file = raw_input("Python file to convert:")

    setup(console=[file])
```

Then, when I enter in the program I want to convert, it says:

```
    usage: setup.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
        or: setup.py --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
        or: setup.py --help-commands
        or: setup.py cmd --help

    error: no commands supplied
```

And then it stops. Do any of you know what could be causing this?

Comment: try `python setup.py py2exe`

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```
python setup.py install
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error as the original poster.
I couldn't get py2exe working, even on a toy hello world-style script.
However:
This worked for me: PyInstaller, more instructions here:
[How to make a Python script standalone executable to run without ANY dependency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5458048/how-to-make-a-python-script-standalone-executable-to-run-without-any-dependency)

If it expects arguments, it should take them like this:
put this inside the python script:

```
import sys
thisArg = sys.argv[1]
```

make sure you call it in command prompt with the arguments:

> my_script "argument1"

Note, no .py at the end.

argv[0] is self, the script name itself.